# Is it an SEO disadvantage to have lots of audio files with little text?

Tags: content, audio, cloud

So most SEO strategies, tips, and questions I see are related to writing text.
And if I recall correctly Google likes text (the 70/30 rule)?

I have a platform for DJs where they can upload and download audio files. This is the core of my platform. I don't have a lot of text. I have a blog page and I do plan on writing some articles to boost my chances, but on a page of an audio sample that a user uploads I wouldn't and can't really put a lot of text apart from a short description of the file you see in the picture below:
[image: a screenshot of a sample page on my website]

As you see, not a lot of text. Normally a sample does have up to 24 related samples below, but they are just cards with the title and image and a more shorter description as the sample what the page is about.

I'm wondering if this puts me at a disadvantage, especially with the new rules coming where Google punishes sites where they think their content is written by bots.

Comment: Yes, this likely puts you at a disadvantage, especially if the audio files do not relate to your business.    I don't think you will be punished for the content though.

Comment: @davidgo do you think there is some counter measure i can take? or is this part of the game? luckely music & soundfiles are the core of my business but i do have other pages with a lot of text. How do other media companies do this? a soundcloud or spotify page doesn't have a lot of text either.